# How to copy folders based upon a condition in ssis

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, etl, ssis

There is  a source folder which conain folders with the name of different countries in the world.
The requirement is  to move these folders into 3 different target folders that is EU,America and Asia,based on the condition .How to achieve this in ssis.
I do understand the file system task does this..but how to implement the if logic

example:
need to move Denamrk,Uk to EU folder.........
Canada ,Usa,Cuba to Americas...........
Japan,China to Asia Folder............

Comment: Do you absolutely need to do this in SSIS? Where are your country > region mappings stored (i.e. what tells you which country is in each region). You could actually do this in a stored procedure and call it from SSIS

Comment: I can store the name of countries in a relational table..but the thing is it would be a difficult task to do in t-sql rt?

Comment: If you can enable `xp_cmdshell`, then it's pretty easy as long as you get all the windows permissions correct. Most shops don't allow this though. If `xp_cmdshell` is not an option, then I suggest you should use Powershell or VBScript, or you can go with your original idea of SSIS if you wish. Let me know which option and I can probably help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using for each loop then conditional split to move the file... simple solution

Comment: caN YOU EXPLIAN ..?HOW TO IMPLEMENT CONDITIONAL SPLIT LOGIC